# Check for multiple hash substrings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to check for two different hash substrings and execute different code depending. This is what I have right now:

**Javascript**

```
if(window.location.hash.substring(confirm) {
    $('.confirm').click();  
}

elseif(window.location.hash.substring(thanks) {
    $('.thanks').click();
}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`indexOf`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) with quotes to denote the string you want to search:

```
if(window.location.hash.indexOf('confirm') >= 0) {
    $('.confirm').click();  
}
else if(window.location.hash.indexOf('thanks') >= 0) {
    $('.thanks').click();
}
```

BTW, in your original implementation, you were also missing `)` in the `if` condition.

Comment: I'm getting a "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'" on line 4 of your code

Comment: @colindunnn: Just put an space in `elseif` eg `else if`